# What kind of API needs to be exposed to allow outside access to a Hyperledger Fabric private network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

What kind of API needs to be exposed to allow outside access to a Hyperledger Fabric private network?

Are there any specifications describing this?

Thank you in advance for any enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric is designed to develep privated (permissioned) network. So, anyone who wants to acces to the network should have permissions for it. Hyperledger Fabric allows the acces to the network throught certificates, for wich it provides a CA. The CA allows you to control who are going to have acces to the netwotk. You register who you want.

Moreover, Hyperledger Fabric provides you a SDK wich makes it easy to use APIs to interact with a Hyperledger Fabric blockchain. More infor about it [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: in other words, you join the private network with an Oauth2 or OpenID REST call with certificates provided by fabric-CA.